# ArrayToList() ColdFusion?

Tags: arrays, list, coldfusion

I have a query that I'm looping through and appending to array. After loop is done I use `ArrayToList()` with tab delimiter. Problem is that between each row I have an extra empty column. My guess is that command converts last comma to tab delimiter. I still could not find the way to prevent that. Here is my code:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#urlPath#\Roster.xlsx" query="excelData" headerrow="1">

<cfset metadata = getMetaData(excelData)>
<cfset colList = "">

<cfloop index="col" array="#metadata#">
    <cfset colList = listAppend(colList, col.name)>
</cfloop>

<cfset buffer=ArrayNew(1)>
<cfset crlf=chr(13)&chr(10)/>

<cfoutput query="excelData">
    <cfloop index="i" list="#colList#">
        <cfset ArrayAppend(buffer,excelData[i][currentRow])>
    </cfloop>

    //prevents blank row to be created on the end
    <cfif excelData.currentrow eq excelData.recordcount>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(buffer,"")>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(buffer,crlf)>
    </cfif> 
</cfoutput>

//setting tab delimiter 
<cfset test = arrayToList(buffer,chr(9))/>

<cfscript> 
    FileWrite("#urlPath#\Test_Text.txt", "#test#"); 
</cfscript>
```

Here is the output after I run this code:

[image]

And here is what I need my output to look like:

[image]

I choose `ArrayAppend()` because it's much faster than the `ListAppend()`, if anyone can help whit this problem please let me know. Thank you.

If I do cfdump of buffer array this is the output:

```
array
1   LAST_NAME
2   FIRST_NAME
3   BIRTH_DATE 
4   
5   Milos
6   TestOne
7   11/16/97
8
```

Looks like between each row is the blank space row 4 and 8. This is how I fixed the date format issue:

```
<cfoutput query="excelData">
        <cfset thisRow = []>
        <cfset count = 1>
        <cfloop index="i" list="#colList#">
            <cfif count EQ 3 AND excelData[i][currentRow] NEQ "BIRTH_DATE">
                <cfset ArrayAppend(thisRow,dateFormat(excelData[i][currentRow],"mm/dd/yyyy"))>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset ArrayAppend(thisRow,excelData[i][currentRow])>
            </cfif>
            <cfset count++>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(buffer,arrayToList(thisRow, chr(9)))>
    </cfoutput>
```

Comment: well, no, your array is, for example, `['Doe', 'John', '1/1/1900',crlf,'Doe','Jane','1/1/1900']`. If you put a tab between each of those values, there will be a tab both before and after the `crlf`. I would suggest creating a single string for each line in the sheet to insert into buffer (can still be done with arrayAppend and then arrayToList within the output loop) and then a final arrayToList with `crlf` as the delimiter, eliminating the need for the other if statement.

Comment: I generate similar CSV/TAB-based exports... you should trim the data and strip pre-existing TAB from the values you are adding to the array.  I've also had major issues with invisible non-breaking spaces chr(160) from Excel/Word.  Regarding dates, I've had mixed success and prefer to use either "yyyy-mm-dd" or "m/d/yyyy" (Use 4 digits for year or some apps won't see the value as a valid date.)

Comment: @JamesMoberg Do you use ColdFusion trim() function or something else? Also have you used dateFormat() to fix the date problem?

Comment: @KevinB I is not an integer, i represents column names.

Comment: @espresso_coffee To trim non-breaking spaces & strip carriage returns & tabs, you'll need to use your own UDF.  Here's what I use to sanitize CSV output values: https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/dc4915d27d55063390557d839c2cfee5

Comment: Do not use `dateFormat(excelData[i][currentRow],"mm/dd/yyyy")`. With two digit years it will return the wrong answer in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array is, for example,

```
['Doe', 'John', '1/1/1900',crlf,'Doe','Jane','1/1/1900']
```

If you put a tab between each of those values, there will be a tab both before and after the `crlf`.

I would suggest creating a single string for each line in the sheet to insert into buffer and then a arrayToList with `crlf` as the delimiter, also eliminating the need for the if statement.

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#urlPath#\Roster.xlsx" query="excelData" headerrow="1">

<cfset metadata = getMetaData(excelData)>
<cfset colList = "">

<cfloop index="col" array="#metadata#">
    <cfset colList = listAppend(colList, col.name)>
</cfloop>

<cfset buffer=ArrayNew(1)>
<cfset crlf=chr(13)&chr(10)/>

<cfoutput query="excelData">
    <cfset thisRow = []>
    <cfloop index="i" list="#colList#">
        <cfset ArrayAppend(thisRow,excelData[i][currentRow])>
    </cfloop>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(buffer, arrayToList(thisRow,chr(9)))>
</cfoutput>

// joining to list on crlf
<cfset test = arrayToList(buffer, crlf)/>

<cfscript> 
    FileWrite("#urlPath#\Test_Text.txt", "#test#"); 
</cfscript>
```

And just because: (untested)

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#urlPath#\Roster.xlsx" query="excelData" headerrow="1">

<cfscript>
    metadata = getMetaData(excelData);
    buffer = [];
    crlf = chr(13)&chr(10);

    for (data in excelData) {
        thisRow = ArrayMap(metadata, function (col,i) {
            return data[col];
        });
        ArrayAppend(buffer, arrayToList(thisRow,chr(9)));
    }    

    test = arrayToList(buffer, crlf);

    FileWrite("#urlPath#\Test_Text.txt", "#test#"); 
</cfscript>
```

Comment: one more question, I have an issue with the date format. I'm missing two digits year is showed like this 01/01/16 instead of 01/01/2016. When I used list I was doing something like this to fix that: <cfif count EQ 3 AND data[i][currentRow] NEQ "BIRTH_DATE">
 <cfset myFile = listAppend(myFile,dateFormat(rowData,"mm/dd/yyyy"),chr(9))>
       </cfif> What you would recommend in this code above? Which way to approach? Also can you elaborate the difference one more time between my code and your solution? Why we use second arrayTo List in your code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would handle that inside the colList loop on each iteration. I split the one arrayToList to two to avoid having tabs on both sides of the crlf. It's either that, or listAppend, or not using arrays at all.

Comment: I updated my question with the code sample of how I fixed the dateFormat(). Thank you!

Comment: *one more question* @espresso_coffee - Please do not tack on new questions in the comments. On SO it is one question per thread  :) That answer to why are the years two digits [can be found on your other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849910/cf-spreadsheet-date-format-outputting-two-digits-only). *When you pass those **strings** into DateFormat ...[they are interpreted] according to CF's rules, two digit years are interpreted as follows: Years 0-29 are interpreted as 2000-2029; years 30-99 are interpreted as 1930-1999.*

Comment: @KevinB cfscript example throwing an error: Variable ARRAYMAP is undefined. Might be because I'm on CF10.

Comment: @espresso_coffee that's possible. I'm unfamiliar with what version of ACF added what, we've been using railo (and now lucee) for years. You should be able to replace it with a loop instead.